# ratchet with angular js implementation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ratchet

I've been googling around and looking for examples on implementations with [ratchet](http://socketo.me/) and angular js and php as my server. But no luck, I'm still not that advanced in angular, but I have a experience with ratchet. If there was a way on doing this where should I put the following codes in my angular app?

```
var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
conn.onopen = function(e) {
   console.log("Connection established!");
};

conn.onmessage = function(e) {
   console.log(e.data);
};
```

Comment: Any ideas guys? Or am I asking the wrong question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anthony,

You'll want to put the connection part into a service, so that it'll only get created once.  Like this:

```
app.factory("Ratchet", function () {

    return new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');

});
```

And then in your controllers you can do something like this (untested, but you should get the basic idea):

```
app.controller("MyController", function ($scope, Ratchet) {

    Ratchet.onopen = function(e) {
        console.log("Connection established!");
    };

    Ratchet.onmessage = function(e) {
        console.log(e.data);

        $scope.message = e.data;
        $scope.$apply();
    };

});
```

This will allow you to receive messages in any controller that 'Ratchet' is injected into.